# Apache Camel route as a Windows Service

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Apache Camel route that is exported as a runnable jar file from eclipse. I use a simple bat file to run this route...

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre6\bin\java -jar C:\dev\_exports\mdt\cpnnectors_v1.jar
```

How can I run this as a window service instead with the output from the console to a log file?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some general windows tools you can use to turn Java apps into services. And I vaugely recall something added to the JDK6 or 7 to support that natively. Anyway try to google a bit.

Tanuki has been around for a long time and they offer such a tool
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit of a late answer but I have managed to deploy my Camel Routes to Apache Karaf and Karaf comes with a service wrapper for both for windows and a deamon wrapper for linux. Basically I know have my Camel routes deployed to Karaf and it is running as a service on windows with really minor hassle.

Karaf is easy to install and the help file also show you how to install the wrapper.